# Request for photo on google places api returns random string of unicode characters

Tags: node.js, api, google-maps-api-3, request, google-places-api

I am making a request on the google places api in node.js to get a photo for a place and im using the npm package request, 
my code(coffeescript):

```
require('dotenv').config()
request = require 'request-promise'

request
  url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=960&photoreference=CoQBcwAAADKQ2XtwPAlXoF2ZFmfslEF_vibsRnoxY-zdlP9Z5LkfbWlq5HZJE4bwFBZXcweP_ENi69zRJuhQzM_-DYagypFOOT03FZNpcsrTPn-EdJoBNOpE3S1vM4H4i9izJTKI2SMYVtPzdRipahmyHwMxGqoawwey9ZKbzLdnjgECfPodEhA5fjpG4QjCPqV_7yzylRNUGhTuAhz-8JhXqnQeYiuv64ekgMxcSQ&key=' + process.env.GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY
.then (response) ->
  console.log response
.catch (err) ->
  console.log err
  return
return
```

The request works fine if I patse the url in my broswer and put in the api key, but when I run the node file it returns a random string of mostly unicode chracters. 
The response is huge, but here is a sample of what most of it looks like:

����!�m iWڵX��Ih�/׹��F�%��7��=��N)��<������^�:=˝�6�_�v���^�&��`�Zr� ����z���yGs�
�[�ɭu?;3mo$�э��B98����(������(��/з���U�h��!��j[C����fx��T�y+eVh�n�+�y/u�3T��zR9SLiH$֚ =I"1��~�TH'�P()=F���� u��֡�(Bs�M����V}6�u=�d���IB����j�)�$t������;)%�O��X\⎼���⎺⎻�ڒRSݿZ%┬���3�≤ �� ��S�����^�UR┤⎺F␍�F㢹��ڈ�┼F�W�─=&��J�+�Ԇ�┤���Q£�2K9�O̦ǉ%$Z�����M��@�-���MX �T�4│�]␤�I�F�4┘@┼─&�␤��Z⎺┘3������┴�2│��Ⱥܱ\�[┘␊─��S─3���␤)�⎺°V─�^�=N*│��F�@��9�3�2S▒P�&�ƇG.���@��Hl)6��Qx$G�Y6�-ʩ���[�d��rV�7���y=����K+�A�D�EM�7��Z~��R�����:�#kӸ�n�i9��vK,$��&rG���zn�*�N�Ź����#ׯr��/

anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to use .pipe and fs to save the file like this:

```
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the full code for that request? I have tried implementing your answer with no luck.

Comment: Hi tinOfBeans, my code was pretty specific and had a lot of database stuff in it.  If you make a new question and put what you've already tried and link it to me here I can try and help

Comment: Thank you @jmona789, I asked a question here a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778775/react-native-how-can-i-display-an-image-returned-by-google-place-photos-api