# React Native - How can I display an image returned by Google Place Photos API?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-places-api, google-places

I have developed a backend API which given the latitude and longitude of a location it returns an image for the city using [Google Places Photos API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos)

My React Native app calls the endpoint to try and load the image into an `Image` view. This is how the app calls the endpoint and receives the response...

```
  try {
    let imageResponse = await fetch(
      `https://budgettrip.herokuapp.com/locationimage/${latitude}/${longitude}`
    );
    let response = await imageResponse;
    this.setState({ locationImage: response });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('location image error', error);
  }
```

The backend code for getting an image from Google and sending the response back to my React Native app...

```
var locationimage = {
    uri: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=${photo_reference}&sensor=false&maxheight=1600&maxwidth=1600&key=${process.env.GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}`,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    }
  };

  rp(locationimage)
    .then(function(repos) {
      res.send(repos);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // API call failed...
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Could not get image' }));
    })
```

You may try the endpoint to see what the response looks like on success [here](https://budgettrip.herokuapp.com/locationimage/-8.409518/115.188919)

I am not sure how to display the image from the response in an `Image` view since the response is not a network image with a url or a local file.

Answer (score 1):

The Photos API returns an image like this:
    https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1wzlVdxiW14/USSFZnhNqxI/AAAAAAAABGw/YpdANqaoGh4/s1600-w400/Google%2BSydney

which you can use in an Image component as you would with any other network image:

```
<Image
  style={styles.image}
  source={{
    uri:'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1wzlVdxiW14/USSFZnhNqxI/AAAAAAAABGw/YpdANqaoGh4/s1600-w400/Google%2BSydney'
  }}
/>
```

I think the problem in your case is that your response is not an actual image, I mean if you hit it in a browser you'll see no image just some encoded image data. Try to add some content type headers in your response like this and see if it will work:

```
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
```